# updating a binary file without overwriting it -> C

Tags: c, file, binary

I am trying to update a binary file that has inside some of these structures:

```
typedef struct _test{
char question[100];
char answer[100];
}test;
```

At some point, I want to update one of the answers that is kept inside of a file to another answer (writing back again the answer to the file), still, everytime I update the file it will erase everything and write only the new test structure (tried in fopen with modes wb, wb+ and even wa+ and settinng the cursor with fseek but no luck).

How can I edit the file so it doesn't wipe the entire file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fopen("myfile.txt", "r+b")`.

Comment: it will write in the file in binary? or the rb+ mode do the trick?

Comment: John: Yes "rb+" or "r+b" will use binary mode. (I'm surprised to see the MS docs say that the "b" must not appear as the first character (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx); I'll edit to fix this.)

Comment: It's not just MS; `b` is never valid as the first character. The only valid `mode` arguments to `fopen` are given by the regular expression `[arw](b?[+]?|[+]?b?)`. Nothing else is valid.

Comment: @R..: Where does it say this?  I thought "b" and "t" existed only on DOS & Windows anyway, and were just politely ignored by other platforms.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: In the standard, 7.19.5.3 paragraph 3. "Text" mode is default and is allowed to be so broken that you should basically *always* use the `b` flag. POSIX requires the behavior of text and binary modes to be identical anyway. Some DOS/Windows implementations add a `t` flag so that they can can have binary mode be default and still support "text mode" for CRLF conversion. This behavior is grossly non-conformant.